# Associate highlighting with file name instead of its extension in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-plugin

Is it possible to associate a particular custom syntax highlighting to files with a particular name? For example all files named "runfile" will be treated as programming language "foo".

Comment: The [ApplySyntax](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax) package should be able to do this, unless you literally mean a file with no extension, in which case you can do that natively in Sublime.

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes, I mean a file with no extension! Could you please explain a bit more what you mean by "doing it natively"? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my comment left something unsaid; do you mean "any file with no extension" or that there is a specific single file name with no extension?

Comment: @OdatNurd The latter: There is a specific file name that I want associated with a syntax. For example all files named "runfile" should be detected as input for a particular software and highlighted accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's somewhat counter-intuitive, Sublime Text treats filenames with no extensions the same way that it treats file extensions for the purposes of syntax detection. This is what allows it to associate the filename `Makefile` with the appropriate syntax, for example.

As such, in order to set things up the way you want you just need to take the same steps that you would take to associate a particular extension in Sublime with a syntax, which is:

1. Open a file of the type (or in this case name) that you want to set the syntax for and ensure that it's the currently active file
2. Select `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as...` from the menu (or click the current syntax name in the status bar) and select the appropriate syntax.

Once you do that, the file should immediately be switched to the appropriate syntax if it wasn't already, and closing and reopening it should apply the correct syntax as well.

This works for any file that doesn't carry an extension, but gets unwieldy quickly if the names of those files change. In your particular case that doesn't matter because all files are named `runfile`.

If you require this ability for a list of filenames (whether with an extension or not) that would require a plugin or add on package that catches the `on_load` event and alters the syntax of the file.

There may or may not be such a package already on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/); [ApplySyntax](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax) for example may be able to do this.

Comment: also potentially relevant for the future is this open issue: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1353#issuecomment-246982762